# Send entire cloudwatch logs to slack when aws codebuild is finished

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have created a lambda function that send codebuild cloudwatch logs to slack. Its working but everytime the logs is generated while codebuild is running. It is throwing messages to slack like a spam.

**I would want to send entire codebuild logs only once when the codebuild is finished.**

I am not sure how to add trigger because in lambda I used cloudwatch trigger for lambda to work.

[image: cloudwatch logs trigger]

Nodejs Lambda function

````
const zlib = require("zlib");
const https = require("https");
const SLACK_ENDPOINT ="/services/000000000000000000000000000000000000"
const SLACK_BOT = "deploy-notifications";

function doRequest(content) {
  // formatting the message according Slack API
  const payload = {
    username: SLACK_BOT,
    blocks: [
      {
        type: "header",
        text: {
          type: "plain_text",
          text: "Whoops, looks like something went wrong ",
          emoji: true,
        },
      },
      {
        type: "section",
        fields: [
          {
            type: "mrkdwn",
            text: "<!here> the API is running into an issue",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        type: "section",
        fields: [
          {
            type: "mrkdwn",
            text: "*Environment: * Production",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        type: "section",
        fields: [
          {
            type: "mrkdwn",
            text: "*Message:* _" + content.message + "_",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        type: "section",
        fields: [
          {
            type: "mrkdwn",
            text: "*Stacktrace:*",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        type: "section",
        text: {
          type: "mrkdwn",
          text:
            "```" +
            JSON.stringify(content.original ? content.original : content) +
            "```",
        },
      },
      {
        type: "divider",
      },
    ],
  };

  const payloadStr = JSON.stringify(payload);
  const options = {
    hostname: "hooks.slack.com",
    port: 443,
    path: SLACK_ENDPOINT,
    channel: "#deploy-notifications",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Content-Length": Buffer.byteLength(payloadStr),
    },
  };

  const postReq = https.request(options, function (res) {
    const chunks = [];
    res.setEncoding("utf8");
    res.on("data", function (chunk) {
      return chunks.push(chunk);
    });
    res.on("end", function () {
      if (res.statusCode < 400) {
        console.log("sent!!!");
      } else if (res.statusCode < 500) {
        console.error(
          "Error posting message to Slack API: " +
            res.statusCode +
            " - " +
            res.statusMessage
        );
      } else {
        console.error(
          "Server error when processing message: " +
            res.statusCode +
            " - " +
            res.statusMessage
        );
      }
    });
    return res;
  });
  postReq.write(payloadStr);
  postReq.end();
}

function main(event, context) {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = true;
  // always returns the last event
  const payload = Buffer.from(event.awslogs.data, "base64");
  const log = JSON.parse(zlib.gunzipSync(payload).toString("utf8"));
  // the log is an object that contains an array of events called `logEvents` and we need access it bypassing the index 0
  doRequest(log.logEvents[0]);
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify("Event sent to Slack!"),
  };
  return response;
}

exports.handler = main;
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**STEP 1**

You should change your trigger for AWS CloudWatch Events / AWS EventBridge rule to achieve this. Instead of using AWS CloudWatch logs event, you should use `AWS CodeBuild Build State Change` event as detail-type and `aws.codebuild` as source.

Below is a sample for that:

```json
{
  "source": ["aws.codebuild"],
  "detail-type": ["CodeBuild Build State Change"],
  "detail": {
    "project-name": ["<PROJECT_NAME>"],
    "build-status": ["SUCCEEDED", "FAILED", "STOPPED"]
  }
}
```

This will trigger the AWS Lambda function when the AWS CodeBuild project build has finished with any of the above mentioned 4 states. It will also send AWS CodeBuild project build ID in event payload.

**STEP 2**

You need to update your AWS Lambda function code accordingly to fetch AWS CloudWatch logs using AWS CodeBuild project build id received in event payload. Your AWS CloudWatch log group name and stream for an AWS CodeBuild project build may look like this `/aws/codebuild/<PROJECT_NAME>/<BUILD_ID>`. It depends upon how you configured it on AWS CodeBuild project.

Below is a sample code for AWS Lambda function for this in Python:

```py
import boto3
import requests
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    build_id = event['detail']['build-id'].split(':')[-1]

    logs_client = boto3.client('logs')

    log_group_name = "/aws/codebuild/" + event['detail']['project-name']
    log_stream_name = build_id

    response = logs_client.get_log_events(
        logGroupName=log_group_name,
        logStreamName=log_stream_name,
        startFromHead=True
    )

    message = {
        'text': 'Logs for build {0}:\n'.format(build_id)
    }

    for event in response['events']:
        message['text'] += event['message'] + '\n'

    slack_webhook_url = <SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL>

    response = requests.post(slack_webhook_url, json=message)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': 'Message is sent to Slack successfully.'
        }
    else:
        return {
            'statusCode': response.status_code,
            'body': 'Failed to send message to Slack.'
        }
```

Here is the documentation by Slack regarding Webhook URL: [Sending messages using Incoming Webhooks](https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks#setup_incoming_webhooks)

**Notes:**

- `<PROJECT_NAME>` is the name of the AWS CodeBuild project
- `<BUILD_ID>` is the build id of the AWS CodeBuild project for a specific build.
- `<SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL>` is the Slack Webhook URL.

Answer (score 2):

@abdullah's answer should solve your problem. However I will post an alternate approach

You can simply enable [notifications on your build project](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dtconsole/latest/userguide/concepts.html#events-ref-buildproject). You can configure which event you want either on Build state or Build phase and configure target for this notification as sns.

In your sns subscribe to lambda and thats it.

You won't have to create a custom event rule or anything just configure event notification rule on your codebuild project.

How to configure notification :

- go to your codebuild project
- on top, click on notify
- Enter notification rule name, chose which event you want and select target

[image]

**Note:** ***My answer assumes your lambda is doing what you intend to do.***

Comment: And at last add that sns as a trigger in aws lambda right ? does it send entire codebuild logs ? or only status of codebuild

Comment: yes add sns a trigger for aws lambda or you can directly subscribe your lambda to sns topic build are the same thing. No it does not send entire codebuild logs, it only sends the status of codebuild depending on the event type. If the answer helped you, do accept it so that it help others in the future

Comment: thanks for your answer @Jatin but I actually need entire logs in my slack. I already have codebuild status send to slack. I want entire logs so that if the build fails developer can see the logs in slack atleast.

Comment: But that wasn't the original question it was about how to trigger. And also Instead of sending entire logs just send the codebuild logs URL in your slack message and let the User navigate to the link and check the logs, there is an environment variable inside codebuild which exposed this URL

Comment: My question title clearly state that `Send cloudwatch logs to slack`.  Right now while running codebuild it is updating cloudwatch logs at the same time and everytime the logs is updated it is sending notification in slack. I just want entire cloudwatch logs for that codebuild at once after codebuild is finish.